# An exam sheet in a stylish format

Tags: formatting, exam

I will take an examination from my students. I wish to prepare a sheet as below format:

[image]

The number of questions must be set on the left recatngular and the questions' points on the right one with inserted logo.

Does anyone have experience with this style?

Answer (score 1):

So many ideas comes to my mind. You can use tabular type-setting. You may use mini-pages. You can write functions to automate this. As long as I see no MWEs for your question, I would suggest looking at existing packages like [exam](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) on CTAN. I think it is a good package for such a purpose.